# ruby Digest::Sha2 -> convert to Nodejs

Tags: ruby, node.js, hash, cryptography, digest

```
newImageName = gameName + consoles[0] # + ".jpg"
newImageName = newImageName.sub("\n", " ").gsub(/[\s+\/]/,'')
i = Digest::SHA2.new << newImageName
i = "#{i}.jpg"
```

^^ this is the code for the ruby side I am converting to nodejs. gameName + consoles[0] is just string values.

I have tried probably 10 different things, and cannot seem to replicate the hashing in Node.js

Comment: here is the last node.js code I used

var imgName = single.name + single.consoles[0]; 
single.img = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(imgName.trim().replace(" ", "")).digest('hex');

Comment: I have no idea what the base is for ruby hashing.. I tried base64 and that was not it. Neither was hex.

Comment: Ok so it turns out if works somewhat... just not consistent.